# How do I check that every object in my Ruby array has a nil attribute?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null, attributes

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  Let's say I have an array of `MyData` instances. Each object has an attribute `attr1`.  Given my array

```
array = [myobj1, myobj2, myobj3]
```

How do I check that every object in the array contains a `nil` value for `attr1`?

Comment: Do you want to filter out the objects with `nil` `att1`'s?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this

```
my_arr.all? { |my_obj| my_obj.attr1.nil? }
```

Comment: I like this answer better because of the readability. It is reading like exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

> How do I check that every object in the array contains a `nil` value for
>   `attr1`?

```
array
  .map(&:attr1) # maps by attr1
  .compact      # removes nil values from collection
  .empty?       # checks, whether array is empty
```

---

### Note, that the below does not differentiate between `false` and `nil` values.

[Enumerable#`none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F):

> The method returns `true` if the block never returns `true` for all
>   elements. If the block is not given, `none?` will return `true` only if
>   none of the collection members is `true`.

It can be shortened to just

```
array.map(&:attr1).none?
```

Or even shorter (*I bet this is the shortest one possible :D (without crazy metaprogramming)*)

```
array.none?(&:attr1)
```

which basically checks, whether none of the `object.attr1` is truthy.

Comment: What about `array.map(&:attr1).all?(&:itself)`?

Comment: @Ursus awesome idea, absolutely

Comment: Cool, even better the last one :)

Comment: @Ursus I realized I should have used `none?` rather then `all?` :)

Comment: Yes. At one point that was not what the user asked :D Now it's correct

Comment: @ndn actually added this note before seeing your comment :)

Comment: Also why make it more complicated than needed. You could have done `array.map(&:attr1).map(&:itself).map(&:itself).map(&:itself).none?(&:itself)` as well, but `array.none?(&:attr1)` is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: @ndn my first solution does differentiate between `nil` and `false`, though

Answer (score -1):

The simplest thing is to use `none?` when you want to know if all values are `nil`:

```
[nil, nil].none? # => true
[true, nil].none? # => false
```

Or you can use `any?` and toggle the boolean result:

```
![nil, nil].any? # => true
![true, nil].any? # => false
```

Extending that to fit your object:

```
class MyData
  def initialize(b)
    @attr1 = b
  end

  def attr1
    @attr1
  end
end

obj1 = MyData.new(nil)
obj2 = MyData.new(true)

[obj1, obj1].none?(&:attr1) # => true
[obj1, obj2].none?(&:attr1) # => false
```

This will break down if you can have `false` values and want to consider them different than `nil` because `none?` considers `nil` and `false` values the same:

```
[false].none? # => true
```

(`any?` and `all?` also get fooled by the truthiness of a value.)

To work around that I'd add a method to the class that tests whether that attribute is actually `nil`:

```
def nil?
  @attr1.nil?
end
```

Then something using `all?` works:

```
obj3 = MyData.new(false)
[obj1, obj1].all?(&:nil?) # => true
[obj1, obj2].all?(&:nil?) # => false
[obj1, obj2, obj3].all?(&:nil?) # => false
```